# Send protobuf data over REST using openAPI

Tags: java, rest, swagger, protocol-buffers, openapi

I have a client that prepares data in the protocol buffers format. I want to send that data over http using REST api. I am using openAPI specification.

Questions:

1. Should I save proto data in a `.bin` file POST that or in the form of bytes array?
2. What should be corresponding openAPI specification for the above case?

I tried:

I stored and POSTed the proto data in a `.bin` file.

openAPI specs

```
        required: true
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              required:
                - logData
              properties:
                logData:
                  type: string
                  format: binary
```

Exception: `Message: Internal server error. org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No multipart config for servlet`

Language: JAVA